# What other alternatives exist for XML-to-XML transformation other than XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt, transform

I've huge XML files (3000+ unique nodes) that need to be translated from 1 format to another format. My main concern is about the speed and memory usage. Are there any alternatives to XSLT for this other than programatically parsing the input XML using StAX and creating the target XML using StAX?

I know there is a STX project but I doesn't think it is being maintained.

Comment: 3000 nodes isn't "huge". As for efficiency, it is the result of efficient algorithms, not of programming language choice. Assembler language programs that implement an O(N^3) algorithm have been shown to execute thousands of times slower than a Basic program that implements a more efficient algorithm -- even fro moderate values of N. Define the exact problem and then people could provide efficient implementation in XSLT. Do you have at all any idea what needs to be optimized? To quote Knuth: "*Premature optimization is the root of all evil*"

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Thank you for your suggestion. I am aware of what Knuth said as well ;-). I am just trying to see if there are some tools out there which I am not aware of. For e.g Saxon's streaming support

Comment: @Pangea, In this case you need to edit the title of the question to more closely reflect its true meaning. Something like: "What are the best tools for transforming H U G E xml documents?". XML documents aren't huge in general, so a title as "Alternatives to XSLT for XML-to-XML transformation" is very misleading.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev thx. I've followed your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are so concerned about speed and memory usage you might want to write your own SAX transformer. Whether that's easy enough depends on the complexity of the transformation.

That said - 3000 nodes is not much and I've used [Apache Cocoon](http://cocoon.apache.org) to transform much bigger documents. And STX worked well, too. Not maintained does not necessarily mean it's not working.

Better try the existing solutions and then improve as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Smooks can help you. Handy and fast. http://www.smooks.org/

Answer (score 0):

I've found [JDom](http://jdom.org/) helpful for simple programmatic manipulation of XML structures in Java.